# I have some question about predicting new data in random forest

Tags: r, random-forest

I have some question, when use random forest to X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test.

When train the data, I use like this:

> rf_train <- randomForest(y = y_train, x = X_train, ntree = 1000)

but, I have a question. Which one is correct to predict new data. :

1.

> randomForest(y = y_test, x = X_test, ntree = 1000)

2.

> predict(rf_train, X_test)

please tell me which one is right.

Comment: Have you checked `?predict.randomForest`

Comment: @akrun I did :-) ... I did a bunch of work with R and the `randomForest` package a while back.  I still actually remember some of it ^ ^

Answer (score 2):

In a situation like this, you can use a combination of the function signature along with your intuition (and the documentation) to answer your own question.  The `predict` function is what you should be using to apply the random forest model to new test data.  As you are calling it, `predict` takes as the first parameter the model output from the call to `randomForest`.  And it takes as the second parameter a data frame or matrix containing the test data, one row for each test case.  As the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/randomForest/versions/4.6-14/topics/predict.randomForest) mentions, the output, at least in the case of a random forest model built using regression, is a vector of responses, one response for each test case/row of the input matrix/data frame of test cases.